# Elasticsearch - get source field data with java api

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I'm using elastic search with jest (as java client).
I need some fields that is in nested document and since cannot get nested fields as pair, I need '_source' to get them.

Here is previous question to get them in ES query[ [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651712/elasticsearch-get-nested-fields) ], and It works well.

BUT cannot convert its query as jest code.
Below is my try.

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder().query( 
            query
        )
        .fields(      // need _source but no method.
          "oid", 
          "_source.events.activityoid", 
          "_source.events.worktime");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [`fetchSource()`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/cd88b7724e9d098d9d1a1b83a6c9bb688a0fd9ae/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/builder/SearchSourceBuilder.java#L659-L673) like this:

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
    .query(query)
    .fetchSource(new String[] {
      "oid", 
      "events.activityoid", 
      "events.worktime"
    }, null);
```