# Filtering Source using the Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to limit my Java API-run Elasticsearch queries so that they only return some specific fields from `_source`.

The analogous query using the REST API looks like:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/ci_person/t/_search?q=name_s:ben&_source=name_s
```

How do I do this in Java?

`searchRequestBuilder.addFields(<array of fields>);` only returns set fields, but in doing so it completely changes the structure of the returned data (replacing `_source` with a nested `field` object). This isn't acceptable for what I'm doing, because specifying a set of fields to return shouldn't completely change what's returned.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654281/elasticsearch-get-source-field-data-with-java-api/38657522#38657522

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I need.