# Elasticsearch get nested value from complex structure

Tags: elasticsearch

My question a bit similar to [Elasticsearch - get nested fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651712/elasticsearch-get-nested-fields)

but my data is more complex, so nested field in my case is array of dicts **keywords**:

```
keywords = [{'key': key1, 'value': value1}, {'key': key2, 'value': value2}, ...]
```

Is there any way to get only some value specifying it somehow in _source, for example I need value where key = key2?

Or the only way is to get all keywords and parse it manually in my script?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using Elasticsearch [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html).

Assuming your index has documents similar to:

```
....
"key_list" : [
    {"key" : "key1", "value" : "value1"},
    {"key" : "key2", "value" : "value2"}, 
    ....
]
```

Then you can query the same as follows:

```
GET index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term" : { "key_list.key" : "key2" } 
    }
}
```

And, for getting only specific values in result instead of entire response JSON, you can try using [filter_path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) clause.

```
GET index/_search?pretty&filter_path=hits.hits._source.*.value
{
    "query": {
        "term" : { "key_list.key" : "key2" } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but it doesn't work for me. Maybe because some subdicts has additional parameters?

Comment: Yeah, would help for clarity purposes if you could post the part of your index document.

Comment: oh, sorry, it's ok, it was just complex value, also may have subarray and subdict, so the original question still valid